# KDE Kmail invite emails do not contain answer options

Tags: kde, kmail

I have an issue with meeting invite emails. In the Zimbra web client I can click to accept or decline invites, but the same mail in the Kmail client does not show any option, just the `.ics` file as attachment.

This is the case for invites from Zimbra and Google Calender. Is there any option I might have missed?

Comment: I have never used this myself but in KMail Settings under "Misc" there should be a tab "invitations" with various options - have you tried playing around with these?

Comment: That is what I thought, but there is also a Plugin. I did not look further, after finding that options.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is strange. There is a plugin for that, but you have to reboot the system for it to enable.

Just go to Setting -> Configure -> Plugins -> Message viewer and select "Create Event". After a reboot, it should work.